# How can I implement a voting system on my site limiting votes to a single vote?

Tags: php

I am trying to build a site with news links that can be voted, I have the following code:

```
 case 'vote':
                require_once('auth/auth.php');
                if(Auth::isUserLoggedIn())
                {
                    require_once('data/article.php');
                    require_once('includes/helpers.php');

                    $id = isset($_GET['param'])? $_GET['param'] : 0;
                    if($id > 0)
                    {
                        $article = Article::getById($id);
                        $article->vote();
                        $article->calculateRanking();
                    }
                    if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
                    redirectTo($_SESSION['action'], $_SESSION['param']);
                }
                else
                {
                    Auth::redirectToLogin(); 
                }
                break;
```

The problem right now is how to check so the same user does not vote twice, here is the article file:

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config.php'); 
require_once(SITE_ROOT.'includes/exceptions.php'); 
require_once(SITE_ROOT.'data/model.php');
require_once(SITE_ROOT.'data/comment.php');

class Article extends Model 
{
    private $id;
    private $user_id;
    private $url;
    private $title;
    private $description;
    private $ranking;
    private $points;

    function __construct($title = ' ', $description = ' ', $url = ' ', $username = ' ', $created = ' ', $modified = '') {

        $this->setId(0);
        $this->setCreated($created);
        $this->setModified($modified);
        $this->setUsername($username);
        $this->setUrl($url);
        $this->setTitle($title);
        $this->setDescription($description);
        $this->setRanking(0.0);
        $this->setPoints(1); 
    }

    function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }

    private function setId($value){
        $this->id = $value;
    }

    function getUsername(){
        return $this->username;
    }

    function setUsername($value){
        $this->username = $value;
    }

    function getUrl(){
        return $this->url;
    }

    function setUrl($value){
        $this->url = $value;
    }

    function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    function setTitle($value) {

        $this->title = $value;
    }

    function getDescription() {

    return $this->description;
    }

    function setDescription($value)
    {
        $this->description = $value;
    }

    function getPoints()
    {
        return $this->points;
    }

    function setPoints($value) 
    {
        $this->points = $value;
    }

    function getRanking()
    {
        return $this->ranking;
    }

    function setRanking($value)
    {
        $this->ranking = $value;
    }

    function calculateRanking()
    {
        $created = $this->getCreated();

        $diff = $this->getTimeDifference($created, date('F d, Y h:i:s A'));

        $time = $diff['days'] * 24;
        $time += $diff['hours'];
        $time += ($diff['minutes'] / 60);
        $time += (($diff['seconds'] / 60)/60);

        $base = $time + 2;        

        $this->ranking = ($this->points - 1) / pow($base, 1.5);

        $this->save();
    }

    function vote()
    {
        $this->points++;
        $this->save();
    }

    function getUrlDomain()
    {
        /* We extract the domain from the URL
         * using the following regex pattern
         */

        $url = $this->getUrl();
        $matches = array(); 
        if(preg_match('/http:\/\/(.+?)\//', $url, $matches))
        {
            return $matches[1];
        }
        else
        {
            return $url;
        }
    }

    function getTimeDifference( $start, $end )
    {
        $uts['start']      =    strtotime( $start );
        $uts['end']        =    strtotime( $end );
        if( $uts['start']!==-1 && $uts['end']!==-1 )
        {
            if( $uts['end'] >= $uts['start'] )
            {
                $diff    =    $uts['end'] - $uts['start'];
                if( $days=intval((floor($diff/86400))) )
                    $diff = $diff % 86400;
                if( $hours=intval((floor($diff/3600))) )
                    $diff = $diff % 3600;
                if( $minutes=intval((floor($diff/60))) )
                    $diff = $diff % 60;
                $diff    =    intval( $diff );
                return( array('days'=>$days, 'hours'=>$hours, 'minutes'=>$minutes, 'seconds'=>$diff) );
            }
            else
            {
                echo( "Ending date/time is earlier than the start date/time");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo( "Invalid date/time data detected");
        }
        return( false );
    }



    function getElapsedDateTime()
    {
        $db = null;
        $record = null;

        $record = Article::getById($this->id);
        $created = $record->getCreated();         

        $diff = $this->getTimeDifference($created, date('F d, Y h:i:s A'));
        //echo 'new date is '.date('F d, Y h:i:s A');
        //print_r($diff);

        if($diff['days'] > 0 )
        {
            return sprintf("hace %d dias", $diff['days']);
        }
        else if($diff['hours'] > 0 )
        {
            return sprintf("hace %d horas", $diff['hours']);
        }
        else if($diff['minutes'] > 0 )
        {
            return sprintf("hace %d minutos", $diff['minutes']);
        }
        else
        {
            return sprintf("hace %d segundos", $diff['seconds']);
        }
    }

    function save() {

    /*
            Here we do either a create or
            update operation depending
            on the value of the id field.
            Zero means create, non-zero
            update
    */

        if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
            $this->title = addslashes($this->title);
            $this->description = addslashes($this->description);
        }

        try
        {
            $db = parent::getConnection();
            if($this->id == 0 )
            {
                $query = 'insert into articles (modified, username, url, title, description, points )';
                $query .= " values ('$this->getModified()', '$this->username', '$this->url', '$this->title', '$this->description', $this->points)";
            }
            else if($this->id != 0)
            {
                $query = "update articles set modified = NOW()".", username = '$this->username', url = '$this->url', title = '".$this->title."', description = '".$this->description."', points = $this->points, ranking = $this->ranking where id = $this->id";
            }

            $lastid = parent::execSql2($query);

            if($this->id == 0 )
                $this->id = $lastid;

        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            throw $e;
        }
    }


    function delete()
    {
        try
        {
            $db = parent::getConnection();
            if($this->id != 0)
            {                ;
                /*$comments = $this->getAllComments();
                foreach($comments as $comment)
                {
                    $comment->delete();
                }*/
                $this->deleteAllComments();
                $query = "delete from articles where id = $this->id";
            }
            parent::execSql($query);


        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            throw $e;
        }
    }

    static function getAll($conditions = ' ')
    {
        /* Retrieve all the records from the
         * database according subject to
         * conditions
         */

        $db = null;
        $results = null;
        $records = array();
        $query = "select id, created, modified, username, url, title, description, points, ranking from articles $conditions";
        try
        {
            $db = parent::getConnection();

            $results = parent::execSql($query);

            while($row = $results->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $r_id = $row['id'];
                $r_created = $row['created'];
                $r_modified = $row['modified'];

                $r_title = $row['title'];
                $r_description = $row['description'];

                if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
                {
                    $r_title = stripslashes($r_title);
                    $r_description = stripslashes($r_description);
                }

                $r_url = $row['url'];
                $r_username = $row['username'];
                $r_points = $row['points'];
                $r_ranking = $row['ranking'];

                $article = new Article($r_title, $r_description , $r_url, $r_username, $r_created, $r_modified);
                $article->id = $r_id;
                $article->points = $r_points;
                $article->ranking = $r_ranking;
                $records[] = $article;
            }
            parent::closeConnection($db);
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            throw $e;
        }

        return $records;
    }

    static function getById($id)
    {/*
     *  Return one record from the database by its id */

        $db = null;
        $record = null;

        try
        {
            $db = parent::getConnection();
            $query = "select id, username, created, modified, title, url, description, points, ranking from articles where id = $id";
            $results = parent::execSQL($query);
            if(!$results) {
                throw new Exception ('Record not found', EX_RECORD_NOT_FOUND);
            }

            $row = $results->fetch_assoc();
            parent::closeConnection($db);

            if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
            {
                $row['title'] = stripslashes($row['title']);
                $row['description'] = stripslashes($row['description']);
            }


            $article = new Article($row['title'], $row['description'], $row['url'], $row['username'], $row['created'], $row['modified']);
            $article->id = $row['id'];
            $article->points = $row['points'];
            $article->ranking = $row['ranking']; 
            return $article;

        }
        catch (Exception $e){
            throw $e;
        }
    }

    static function getNumberOfComments($id)
    {/*
     *  Return one record from the database by its id */

        $db = null;
        $record = null;

        try
        {
            $db = parent::getConnection();
            $query = "select count(*) as 'total' from comments where article_id = $id";
            $results = parent::execSQL($query);
            if(!$results) {
                throw new Exception ('Comments Count Query Query Failed', EX_QUERY_FAILED);
            }

            $row = $results->fetch_assoc();
            $total = $row['total'];
            parent::closeConnection($db);    

            return $total;


        }
        catch (Exception $e){
            throw $e;
        }
    }

    function deleteAllComments()
    {/*
     *  Return one record from the database by its id */

        $db = null;
        try
        {
            $db = parent::getConnection();
            $query = "delete from comments where article_id = $this->id";
            $results = parent::execSQL($query);
            if(!$results) {
                throw new Exception ('Deletion Query Failed', EX_QUERY_FAILED);
            }
            parent::closeConnection($db);
        }
        catch (Exception $e){
            throw $e;
        }
    }


    function getAllComments($conditions = ' ')
    {
        /* Retrieve all the records from the
         * database according subject to
         * conditions
         */
        $conditions = "where article_id = $this->id";
        $comments = Comment::getAll($conditions);
        return $comments; 
    }


    static function getTestData($url)
    {
        $page = file_get_contents($url);




    }

}
?>
```

Any suggestion or comment is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: When posting code, it's much appreciated if you cut the code down to just what's relevant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

make another table user_votes for example with structure:
user_id int not null
article_id int not null
primary key (user_id, article_id)

in vote function first try to insert and if insert is successfull then increase $this->points

Answer (score 3):

Have a table that keeps track of a user's vote for an article (something like UserID,ArticleID,VoteTimeStamp).  Then you can just do a check in your `$article->vote();` method to make sure the currently logged in user doesn't have any votes for that article.

If you want to keep thing fast (so you don't always have to use a join to get vote counts) you could have a trigger (or custom PHP code) that when adding/removing a vote updates the total vote count you currently keep in the article table.

Answer (score 3):

You have these options:

Track the IP of whoever voted, and store it in a database. This is bad beucase many people might share IP and it can be circumvented using means such as proxies.

Another solution is to store a cookie in the browser. This is probably a bit better than the first solution as it lets many people from the same IP vote. It is, however, also easy to circumvent as you can delete your cookies.

The last and only secure method is to require your users to register to vote. This way you pair username and password against the votes and can ensure everyone votes only once, unless they are allowed to have several users.

A last solution might be a combination of the first two solutions, it is still obstructable though.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a table containing a users ID and the article's ID called something like article_votes. So when user x votes for article y a row is inserted with both ID's. This allows you to check if a user has voted for an article.

To count the number of articles you could use a query like this: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS votes FROM article_votes WHERE article=[article id]`